# Replacing a motherboard on a Carrier 8000VS Furnace

Tags: wiring, hvac, furnace, board

[image][image][image]

Hi guys, I am trying to finalize the wiring of my new carrier motherboard. I have about four more wires to connect and the new motherboard is slightly different than the old one. The pictures I’ve attached show my most confusing part of this wiring. It looks like these two black wires are basically connected and And basically sharing an L1 terminal.  One of the black wires goes to the blower motor and the other black wire goes up to the furnace.   I tried to connect these Joined wires onto the new motherboard and there just isn’t room.

It says that these are line voltage wires.  It looks like I have to separate them. Where would I connect the other one because only one will fit on the new terminal pictured above with an “A” on it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The bottom picture is the old motherboard, the middle picture is the new one.

Comment: The terminal on the end of the wire you're holding in the top pic should fit onto the A terminal on the board - the terminal on that wire is a sort-of double-stack and can both plug onto A and have the other wire (labeled "1000V 16 AWG") connected to it.

Comment: @brhans -- make that an answer and I'll give you a +1 for it -- only other case I can think of is if the double-stack terminal doesn't fit in the space around the A terminal....